# How to specify interpolation qualifier and layout for the same attribute in shaders VULKAN

Tags: fragment-shader, vulkan

I want to specify interpolation qualifier - FLAT and Layout(location=0) for an input vertex in my fragment shader in VULKAN, but upon compilation to SPIR-V file, it throws an error.

Shader:

```
#version 450
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable
flat in vec3 fragColor;

layout(location = 0) in vec3 fragColor;
layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

void main() {
    outColor = vec4(fragColor, 1.0);
}
```

How do I retain/program the below:

```
flat in vec3 fragColor;
layout(location = 0) in vec3 fragColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `flat` modifier needs to be part of your already declared input layout:

```
layout (location = 0) flat in vec3 fragColor;
```